# Trying to make a quick-sort function that changes the orginal list however it wouldn't make any change on it

Tags: python, recursion, quicksort

Here is the code. I'm not sure why it's not working am still a beginner by the way:

```
def quick_sort(L):
  if len(L)>1:
    L1=[]
    L2=[]
    for i in range(1,len(L)):
      if L[i]<=L[0]:
        L1.append(L[i])
      elif L[i]>=L[0]:
        L2.append(L[i])
    quick_sort(L1)
    quick_sort(L2)
    L=L1+[L[0]]+L2
```

I even tried to do only the first step using the code below but the list wouldn't change:

```
def quick_sort(L):
  if len(L)>1:
    L1=[]
    L2=[]
    for i in range(1,len(L)):
      if L[i]<=L[0]:
        L1.append(L[i])
      elif L[i]>=L[0]:
        L2.append(L[i])
    L=L1+[L[0]]+L2
```

Comment: Change the last line to `L[:]=L1+[L[0]]+L2` and it should work.

Comment: Don't forget to accept (and up-vote) an answer when it answers your question.

Comment: did you solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

You must change the `L=L1+[L[0]]+L2` to `L[:]=L1+[L[0]]+L2`

When you assign a value to `L`, it only rebinds the name, but using `L[:]` will replace what was previously in the list.